# Commit,pull,push. New Merge in gitlab shows changes from other developers under my user

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab, commit

I fail to understand why this is happening,and wasn't able to find same scenario here. I switched from the branch I am working on, to make minor change in master branch and push it straight to the remote. 
After making changes I committed the change and tried pushing it,git complained that this branch has changes and I need to pull. I've done pull,my local changes were merged together with latest changes on master branch.
I checked which commit I am about to push using 'cherry -v',showed only my commit.

Now when I went to see my latest commit in gitlab it shows merge master into master commit and 57changed files,even though I have changed one line in one file.

P.S I know that pushing directly into master is wrong

This issue can be closed,it seems to be a gitlab bug that they are still working on.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15140

If git merge master was performed on the source branch, the "Changes" display in gitlab practically useless because it shows all those merged changes.

Comment: I'm assuming you are pushing to origin? Is origin your public repo or a shared repo? It sounds like you branched off a master then someone else committed to that repo.

Comment: It's shared among 5 other developers. I have cloned master from it,worked on the other branch,switched back and repulled master and pushed with my change. I can confirm that this change does not appear in any other interfaces for git,like Tortoise Git or Sourcetree,only in Gitlab